# SharePoint Online - Highlight Content web part filtering with parent page properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I am new to SharePoint but I have been tasked with investigating it.

I have added some Custom properties to a Site Page, I have added a Highlight Content web part to this page.

I am now trying to filter the Highlight Content web part using custom property values from the page the web part is embedded into.

Is this even possible? Any tips on what to research?

Answer (score 0):

How did you add custom properties to a site page? Whether through site page content type or in the site pages library? If you through site page content type, it is impossible. If you through site pages library, it is possible.

[image]